# Dynamic loading content via AJAX in Yii?

Tags: php, ajax, yii

**Need**: Dynamic loading content via AJAX in the proper framework Yii. As it is implemented in https://duckduckgo.com/?q=yii Ie when scrolling down a page, the content at the end of the page is automatically added.

**What I have**:

**View:**

```
<!--MAIN CONTENT AREA-->
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="container inner_content">
        <div class="row advertisement_row">
            <!-- portfolio_block -->
            <div class="projects">
<?php
    foreach ($models as $one)
    {
?>
                <div class="span3 element category01 advertisement" data-category="category01">
                    <div class="hover_img">
                        <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?><?=$one->picture_1?>" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_description">
                        <?php $title = implode(array_slice(explode('<br>',wordwrap($one->title,60,'<br>',false)),0,1))."...";?>
                        <h6><?=CHtml::link($title, array('view', 'id'=>$one->id))?></h6>
                        <div class="descr"><?=implode(array_slice(explode('<br>',wordwrap($one->content,240,'<br>',false)),0,1))."..."?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<?php
    }
?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- //portfolio_block -->
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Prompt how to implement this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this without using a Yii extension or jquery plugin, by probing for when the scroll position reaches the bottom of the screen.

This is how I did mine.

```
var page = 0;

function loadnewdata()
{
// do ajax stuff, update data.
     var url         = '$showlistingUrl'+'/page/'+page;

     $.ajax({ url: url,
              cache: false,
              success: function(data){
                var existing_content = $('#listing_container').html();

                 $('#listing_container').replaceWith('<div id="listing_container">'+existing_content+data+'</div>');

                 page++;
              },
              dataType: "html"
                });
}

setInterval(
  function ()
  {
    if(($(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(document).scrollTop()) < 500){
       loadnewdata();
    }
  },
  500
);

// Run the initial listing load.
loadnewdata();
```

The controller page in turn queries the 'page' GET parameter and uses this to fetch data from the database.

```
public function actionShowlisting()
{

    $argPage       = (int) Yii::app()->request->getQuery('page', 0);


    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Get a listing of results
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $dbCriteria             = new CDbCriteria;
    $dbCriteria->limit      = (int) Yii::app()->params['PAGESIZEREC'];
    $dbCriteria->offset     = $argPage * $dbCriteria->limit;


    $listResults   = Mymodel::model()->findAll($dbCriteria);

    $this->renderPartial('result_list', array('listResults' => $listResults));

}
```

Comment: ofcourse you don't **need** a plugin, and btw you can append the new data to the container, using appendTo jquery func,

Comment: Correct and well spotted. My original implementaion tested the containers position within the scrollwindow and I changed this to test the window scroll position instead, but did not change my function.

Answer (score 1):

You need a javascript/jquery plugin like infinite scroll see [www.infinite-scroll.com](http://www.infinite-scroll.com)
which help convert multipage result into single page ones, loaded dynamically as in twitter or duckduckgo.

You directly integrate such a plugin for your page or you can consider couple of integrations available for Yii in the extensions library

1. Infinite Scroll Pager ([link](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/inifinite-scroll-pager))
2. Infinite Scroll ([link](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiinfinite-scroll))

Note that These extensions rely on presence of pagination variable for loading each subsequent page. So they will work best if you use `CListView`, `CGridView` or similar `CPagination` based rendering widget in your view.